# Update meta_value for specific word

Tags: mysql, sql

Tabe I am using is wp_post_meta. It has Id, Meta_key and Meta_value column

I am trying to make an update for all links that are in the meta value where meta_key = description.

I have links in meta_value for ex: "https://test.com/today/11am/" needs to be changed to https://www.test.com/today/11am/

Links are dynamic, but all links that starts with https://test.com/ need to be changed to https://www.test.com/

Besides links in the column, there is another text.

Not sure if this is possible to do through a query, if yes please help somehow.

Comment: this script do what you want : https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all links that starts with https://test.com/ need to be changed to https://www.test.com/

In an update you can do:

```
update t
    set meta_value = concat('https://www.test.com/', substring(meta_value, 17))
    where meta_value like 'https://test.com/%';
```

Note:  You might want some condition on the `meta_key` as well.

Assuming `//` occurs only once in the string (reasonable for a URL), you could simplify this to:

```
update t
    set meta_value = replace(meta_value, '//', '//www.')
    where meta_value like 'https://test.com/%';
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, 2nd query gives me 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0896 seconds.) , first query gives me error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where meta_value like"

Comment: @ron9 . . . Try again.

Comment: Second option worked, I just had to add %https://test.com/% in where condition as I had text before and after link. THanks a lot